# How to enable notification in electron app packaged for windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, node-notifier

I am making an  electron desktop app for windows. I have used [node-notifier](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) and in-built [electron notification](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/notifications). These notifications are fired when I run the app in development. But when I package the app and install it on a windows computer, the notifications fail to fire. What steps should be included while building the app to ensure notifications work? I am using [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) to build the app.

Comment: Did you figure out solution?

Comment: @Noitidart, the requirements changed soon after and we did not have to do it. So I did not get time to explore for a solution

Comment: Darn, thanks though for the reply. What I did for Windows users is use `node-notifier` package, and then for others I'm using built-in `Notification` module. `node-notifier` on Mac has a weird terminal icon (there is a popular issue its github repo)

Comment: @Noitidart why don't you elaborate and answer the question. I'll mark it as answered

Comment: I had to add `appName` for windows - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852798/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart did you test on windows 7 pc?

Comment: No I didnt, do you have win7? I would love to hear if it works.

Comment: No I don't. You can make a Windows 7 VM and check

Comment: Share steps on Win7 VM. Make it basic and super easy for first timer.