# Windows notification not showing for electron app

Tags: windows, notifications, electron, app-id

Windows notification for my electron app is not showing in the latest version of windows. It may because of not giving appid for the shortcut. So Can anyone tell me how to add appid for shortcut while creating msi using visual studio installer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron with node-notifier display windows 10 notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810041/electron-with-node-notifier-display-windows-10-notification)